# What is the function of cv2.destroyAllWindows()?

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('pic.jpg',1)
cv2.imshow("Win",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Even if I don't use cv2.destroyAllWindows() function, pressing any key on my keyboard is closing the image window. So what is its use?

Answer (score 2):

If any related memory usage is not de-allocated, calling `destroyAllWindows` will take care of the de-allocation.

Like you said, if it is simple usage or/and sure of appropriate usage of resources, the call is unnecessary.

You will find this information in associated c++ documentation of opencv

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=destroyallwindows

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Non-Display Window Mode

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```

Then you don't need to execute:

```
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

To de-allocate and close the windows.